# Creating a unique list from dataset too big to fit in memory

Tags: c#, .net, hashset

I have a list of 120 million records of around 40/50 bytes each which is about 5.5/6 gigabytes of raw memory space not including any extra storage required to keep an array in memory.

I'd like to make sure this list is unique. The way I have tried to do it is create a Hashset<string> and add all the entries to it one by one.

When I get to about 33 million records I'm out of memory and the list creation slows to a crawl.

Is there a better way to sort this massive list of entries in a timely manner? The only solution I can think of is using an Amazon EC2 High-Memory Quadruple Extra Large Instance for an hour.

Thanks

Comment: Where is this dataset that you are having stored?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're just trying to check for uniqueness, I would simply split the input sequence into buckets, and then check each bucket separately.

For example, assuming you're loading the data from a file, you could stream the input in, and write it out to 26 different files, one for each letter that record starts with (I'm naively assuming each record starts with A-Z - please adjust for your real situation). Then you can check each of those smaller files for uniqueness using something like your existing code - because none of them will be too large to fit into memory at a time. The initial bucketing guarantees that there won't be any duplicate entries which are in different buckets.

Of course, there are various different ways you could perform the bucketing, and different approaches will be effective for different data sets. You could bucket by hash code, for example - take the bottom 5 bits of the hash code to create 32 different buckets. That's likely to get a *reasonably* equal distribution of records between buckets, and doesn't make any assumptions about the input data. I only mentioned the "take the first letter approach" above as it's a simpler way of grasping the concept :)

Comment: Thanks Jon and Amber this is a great solution which didn't come to mind.

Answer (score 4):

Use [bucket sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) to sort the list, flushing some of the contents of the buckets out to disk regularly to avoid running out of memory. Then load each flushed bucket in sequence and either use your HashSet approach or sort it and check it that way.

Answer (score -1):

You could always work in a sqlite database with a unique index as it may help for further processing on the dataset.